# VueJS: Material Table: How to assign a value from row as the column heading?

Tags: vue.js, material-design

Using the examples from Vue Material documentation, we are creating a table. However, we are stuck at one seemingly minor point - how to assign an item value as the column heading.

```
<md-table v-model="users" md-card>
  <md-table-toolbar>
    <h1 class="md-title">Users</h1>
  </md-table-toolbar>
  <md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{ item }">
    <md-table-cell md-label="{{ item.id }}" md-sort-by="id" md-numeric>{{ item.id }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Name" md-sort-by="name">{{ item.name }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Email" md-sort-by="email">{{ item.email }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Gender" md-sort-by="gender">{{ item.gender }}</md-table-cell>
    <md-table-cell md-label="Job Title" md-sort-by="title">{{ item.title }}</md-table-cell>
  </md-table-row>
</md-table>
```

In this line where we tried out a variable, the output just shows the column heading as "{{item.id}}"

```
<md-table-cell md-label="{{ item.id }}" md-sort-by="id" md-numeric>{{ item.id }}</md-table-cell>
```

Please let us know what we might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: The correct syntax is: `:md-label="item.id"` or `v-bind:md-label="item.id"`.

Comment: Thanks @IgorMoraru, that colon ":" did the trick, works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, thanks to Igor Moraru for his help.

### Right syntax (the : before md-label is important)

```
<md-table-cell :md-label="item.id" md-sort-by="id">{{ item.id }}</md-table-cell>
```